# Posting an array to MVC3 controller using ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

How can I post an array of elements to a controller action using jQuery Ajax post.

This is how I am trying, but my controller recieving a null array.

```
function dipatchAllocations() {
            // unSelected is an array of items of type int.
            if (unSelected.length == 0) {
                alert("Please select a line item to be dispatched.");
                return;
            }
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Batch/SetToDispatch',
                data: '{ "allocationId[]" : "[' + unSelected + ']","batchId" : "' + @Model.Id + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: updateView,
                error: errorInSubscribing
            });
        };
```

And this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetToDispatch(long[] allocationId,long batchId)
{   
  // Perform some action here
   return View("_ReadyToDispatchItems",model);
}
```

Can somebody advice me what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tired removing "[]" after allocationId

Comment: Can you show `unSelected` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = { allocationId : unSelected, batchId : @Model.Id };
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Batch/SetToDispatch',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: updateView,
                error: errorInSubscribing
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json syntax seems to be off, no [] required after  allocationId[]
See: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp
for the syntax on arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give the data to controller as query string it will work

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Batch/SetToDispatch/' + unSelected + ',' + batchId
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
            success: updateView,
            error: errorInSubscribing
        });
```

Its comma seperated you can split it in controller and use it.
Hope it helps